# sans serif math font selection using unicode-math

Tags: fonts, fontspec, unicode-math, etoolbox

I am typesetting a document in XeLaTeX using a serif font for main text, and a sans serif for everything else (section titles, tables etc). For setting of mathematics, I use TeX Gyre Pagella Math. Using `fontspec` and `unicode-math`, this mostly works fine. I use the `etoolbox` package to automatically switch to sans serif for floats. However, mathematics are still typeset in the serif font. I know how to switch to sans serif math (which is available in TGPM) using `\mathsf{…}`, but I would like to automate this. I've tried the `version=…` option of `unicode-math` (in combination with `etoolbox`), but I can't figure out how to make that work. I also couldn't figure out how to make this work using `etoolbox` directly.

Below is an MWE of my current setup; the point is to have the mathematics in the table content in sans serif as well, which is not the case now. To be clear: I use other Komascript options to set the caption labels to sans serif, but left it out here for brevity. Also, in case it matters, I use Minion Pro and Fira Sans as my actual fonts, but not everyone might have those available.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}[%
    Ligatures   = TeX,%
    Numbers     = {OldStyle,Proportional},%
]
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[%
    Ligatures   = TeX, %
    Numbers     = {Lining,Monospaced}, %
    Scale       = MatchLowercase, %
]

\setmathfont[%
    Scale       = MatchLowercase,%
]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math} %

\setmathfont[%
    version     = table,%
    Scale       = MatchLowercase,%
]{TeX Gyre Pagella Math} %

\usepackage{% 
    tabularx,%
    etoolbox,%
}

% etoolbox
\AtBeginEnvironment{tabularx}{%
   \sffamily\addfontfeature{Numbers={Lining, Monospaced}}%
    \mathversion{table}  
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{table}[t]
\centering
\caption{$\mathsf{a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}}$}
\begin{tabularx}{.6\linewidth}{lrr}
some & text & and some math \\
$a^{2}$ & $+b^{2}$ & $=c^{2}$
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{displaymath}
  (x + a)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^k a^{n-k}
\end{displaymath}


\end{document}
```

Comment: `unicode-math` only works with fonts which support mathematics. It works with Pagella because Pagella is one of only a few fonts to support the maths extension for opentype. But Pagella is a serif font, so obviously you won't get sans. Hence, I'm not completely sure that I'm understanding the question.

Comment: You are not switching to "sans serif math" with `\mathbf`, you are only mapping (a rather small) set of glyphs to the sansserif variants. Also imho you should better use `\mathsfit{a}^{\mathsf{2}}` in the caption to get an slanted `a`. Regarding the automation I would have expected that `range={it->sfit, up->sfup }`  would do the mapping you want, but I get errors and @WillRobertson will have to look at it.   (I don't think that two math versions are really a good idea, imho it can get confusing. Math fonts convey meaning).

Comment: @cfr the Pagella Math font includes a few sans serif symbols that can be selected using `\mathsf{}`; as in the `$\mathsf{a^{2}+b^{2}=c^{2}}$` line in my MWE.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Point taken, but I use math in the tables sparingly (but enough that I would like to automate it), and I don't think it would confuse anyone. It's just that a single serif math glyph thrown into sans serif table looks very ugly and unprofessional. The sans serif Pagella Math with my sans serif text font is still not ideal, but better. And I just want to learn how this stuff works…

Comment: OK. That doesn't include any specifically-mathematical symbols. I didn't know Pagella offered sans variants. I assume they are intended to be used for cases where the mathematical symbol should be sans serif, even though the main maths font is serif. (Which is why using them otherwise is likely going to be confusing.) Why are you activating the `T1` font encoding? Do you need it?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Don't you need to limit the effect? e.g. to `latin,Latin,num` or something to avoid trying to map Greek? (I'm not sure what the font has in sans so this might be a bad example.) However, if I use `range  = up/{num,latin,Latin}->sfup,` then some of my numbers disappear and some of my letters. Without that `\mathsf{01293456789}` and `\mathsfup{0123456789}` give different results. With it, those actually give the same output, but bog standard `0123456789` gives nothing at all (in maths mode).

Comment: Don't you need `\DeclareMathVersion{table}`? Or is `table` version a default provided by `unicode-math`?

Comment: @cfr: Restricting the range with `it/{latin,Latin,num}->sfit` works (I think I forgot the slash yesterday).  But it seems not to be possible to restrict the mapping to a math version. It always affects the main math too.

Comment: @cfr The `T1` font encoding is a remnant from the first LaTeX template I received from a colleague years ago…don't think I need it. Does it do any harm?

Comment: Also, operators such as `\log{…}` are still set in the serif font, even though other maths is in sans.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes. I found I could get the sans in. But it seemed to affect everything or nothing and not be restricted to a version. I can't get it to work even if I use a different font for the main maths font and restrict Pagella to the `table` version. But I'm not certain what exactly is required to get a `version` working with `unicode-math`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `version` only seems to work if the font has a maths table and includes the range defined. So it doesn't seem to work at all if you want to take letters or numbers from a text font: the changes affect all maths versions come what may. Is this intended? That is, may this just isn't supposed to work if you try using anything at all from regular text fonts and should only be used with a pure opentype maths configuration? That's my best guess right now - that's how it seems to work.

Comment: @cfr Sorry but I don't currently have the time to investigate unicode-math. There are certainly bugs or deficiencies in the package but as the code is quite complicated one can't debug it without some free time.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. Completely understand. I tried to debug it myself but it would, as you say, take a while to trace things through. Anyway, I found it happens with all-maths fonts, as well, so I've asked a new question. (I suspect it may be a bug, but I'm not familiar enough with `unicode-math` or `fontspec` to be confident. Hopefully somebody who already knows the code can at least clarify the situation ;).)

Answer (score 1):

To avoid ambiguity, for new readers landing, it may be helpful, for reference, to have a visual on the unicode blocks.

Tex Gyre Pagella Math has Basic Latin (call it "text", but mappable)

[image: tgpm_bl]

Greek and Coptic ("text")

[image: tgpm_g]

... lots of other blocks ...

and the Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols (MAS) block:

[image: tgpm_mas1]

and

[image: tgpm_mas2]

(Sidenote: Because of the organic way Unicode has developed, some of the more famous mathematical symbols are located in the earlier Letter-like Symbols block:

[image: tgpm_lls]
)

By comparison, the Fira Sans Math font's MAS is much smaller:

[image: Fira Sans Math MAS]

---

Other Tex Gyre fonts (Bonum, DejaVu, Schola, Termes) have a math version -- see e.g. ...\texmf-dist\fonts\opentype\public\tex-gyre-math\

Answer (score 1):

An old question, but it deserves an answer.

I’m not sure exactly what you want, here.  If you are looking for Termes as your main font, and Fira Sans for everything else, you could use the Fira Math font:

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]
\setsansfont{Fira Sans}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}
```

If you mean you want to be able to switch between `\mathversion{normal}` and `\mathversion{sans}`, you could do something like this:

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]
\setsansfont{Fira Sans}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}[version=sans]

\mathversion{sans}
```

If you want to use letters and numerals from Fira in math mode, but other symbols from Termes, you could try:

```
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}[Scale=1.0]
\setsansfont{Fira Sans}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}[range={up,it,bfup,bfit}]
```

Unfortunately, the `range=` and `version=` options are not compatible with each other, as of 2021.